# X & Y Marking Table Using Php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an x and y marking table using PHP. I used array and loops to this task.
Please refer to the sample code and image. I almost spent 2hrs finding some solutions still need help.
Very much appreciated for some ideas.

```
                  <?php 
                  $x_arr = array();
                  $y_arr = array();
                  $n_arr = array();

                  $x_arr = [5,5,9,14];
                  $y_arr = [1,4,3,3];
                  $n_arr = [1,1,1,1];

                  $x = 16;
                  $y = 4;
                  $gap = 3;
                  $data = "";
              ?>
                  <div style="padding:30px; background:#242424;">
                    <table style="border:20px solid #660000;" align="center">
                      <?php 
                      //STRIP
                        for($i=$y; $i>=1; $i--){
                      ?>
                      <tr style="background:#fff;">
                        <?php 
                          for($ii=$x; $ii>=1; $ii--){
                            //echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>x".$ii." : y".$i."</td>";
                          
                              for($iii=0; $iii<=count($x_arr); $iii++){
                                if(isset($x_arr[$iii]) && isset($y_arr[$iii])){
                                  $x_tmp = $x_arr[$iii];
                                  $y_tmp = $y_arr[$iii];
                                  if($i==$y_tmp && $ii==$x_tmp){
                                    $data= "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; height:30px; text-align:center;'><span data-feather='circle'></span></td>";
                                    echo $data;
                                  }else{
                                    $data = "";
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            
                            if($data == ""){
                              echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>x".$ii." : y".$i."</td>";
                            }
                             
                            //echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>";
                            
                            //echo "<td style='border:1px solid black; width:50px; height:30px; text-align:center;'><span data-feather='circle'></span></td>";

                            if($ii>$gap){
                              $gap = $gap+$gap;
                            }
                        
                          }
                        ?>
                      </tr>
                      <?php 
                        }
                      ?>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

Result Error :
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WejeX.png)

Expected Result :
[Target Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQs5s.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desired result a bit more? What is this table supposed to achieve, how are the pairings done?

Comment: The only problem to this code is the loop. After the circle mark, the beside <td> should be gone. You can see it in the image link I provide. Pairing, I used array. $x_arr and $y_arr.